# firebase retrieve data not working - missing something simple?

Tags: java, android, database

I have a list of "Persons" profiles that contains some usual identifying information.

1. I'm able to add new entries programmatically without any issues.
2. I'm able to retrieve and display in a list the entries in firebase

The issue I am having is with retrieving the profile of the Person whose entry is clicked in the list mentioned above.  The code for this is listed below. I have verified that *thisPersonRef* contains the correct path. As far as I can tell, the event listener is just skipped over/not triggered. I believe I am following the instructions and samples show at https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#attach_an_event_listener

The error I get is:

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.bcll_tech.ptapp.Persons.Person.barCodeText' on a null object reference*

I've also tried using addListenerForSinglevalueEvent as well as ChildEventListener and I get the same results. This makes me think that I must be missing some other step in the process.

Any help is appreciated as I've scoured the list and haven't seen anything quite the same.

Thanks.

---

```
public void onPersonSelected(String listRecordId) {     
    Log.d(logtag, "Activity: List item recordId = " + listRecordId);
    final     Firebase thisPersonRef = mPersonRef.child("barCodeId").child(listRecordId);

    thisPersonRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) { 
            Log.d(logtag, "PersonsListViewDetailsFragment: in listener. snapshot of " + thisPersonRef);
            Person thisPerson = snapshot.getValue(Person.class);
            Log.d(logtag, "From Get Data: Bar Code ID = " + thisPerson.barCodeText + "; Last name = " + thisPerson.lastName);               
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    Log.d(logtag, "Activity: Get Person: BarCodeId = " + thisPerson.barCodeText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 final Firebase thisPersonRef = mPersonRef.child("barCodeId").setValue(listRecordId);
```

and

```
 Person thisPerson = snapshot.getChildren().getValue(Person.class);
```

Comment: akhil, thanks for the quick response. I tried your suggestions, but, they don't help. The first generate, "Incompatible types" error message. The second generates, "Cannot resolve method, 'getValue...'.

Comment: You cannot directly assign string value to firebase.for that you do onething define the POJO class(seperate class in that define listRecordId variable) after that pass that entire class into setValue()